# Determine audio finish state in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I have some trouble with my audio player. I use MPMoviePlayer to play audio stream. I also have an array with my mp3 files. Now what I need is, when audio finish playing, player must play the next track from my array.

1. I checked stackowerflow to find solution and I found:

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
>                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinished)
>                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
>                                               object:[[PlayerPlistController utilise]playerController]];

2. I tried this but it doesn't help
3. I will show my code player, states and others if needed.

Can someone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Normaly i found solution, you must connect UISlider like duration of mp3 file and after check if slider == 100 % make something...on my situation play next track.